# Getting ghosts images on HP Color LaserJet 1600

Tags: laser-printer

I'm getting ghosting (lighter repeats of images going down the page that shouldn't be there). Ghosts appears only when upper-left or upper-right corners of the page are printed. With consequents left or rights margins, there is no ghosting.

I have replaced the fusing assembly (part RM1-1821-000CN) and the electrostatic transfer belt (part RM1-1885-020CN).

Have also employed auto cleaning function, didn't help.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a Drum problem.

From the [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119446)

> Ghosting most often occurs when a large black pattern is followed by a
>   fine gray scale. The condition is caused by residual electrical
>   charges left on the surface of the electro-photographic (EP) drum or a
>   lack of toner in the developer region. Ghosting is a condition
>   experienced in one form or another by all devices that use the
>   electro-photographic (EP) process. Both the developer and the EP-drum
>   can produce dark or light ghosting.   Both light and dark types of
>   ghosting can be caused by either the developer or the EP-drum. The
>   circumference of the developer or EP-drum corresponds to the distance
>   between the repeated images. Therefore, measuring this distance
>   determines whether the EP-drum or the developer is the cause of the
>   ghosting.

Comment: Seem that the electro-photographic (EP) drum are located on the cartridges themselves. I replaced them and now problem is fixed.